# PYQT plot not shown in grid

Tags: pyqt

I have a main window with a grid layout

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

```
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(1850, 1700)  # width, height
    self.gl_main = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)

    w = ChartWidget(self)
    self.gl_main.addWidget(w, 4, 0, 1, 1)


class ChartWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ChartWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.axes.hold(False)
        self.axes.plot(range(10), range(10), 'b')
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.show()
```

The chartwidget is not added to the gridlayout, though. I can briefly see it flash up on the screen, but then it is gone. how do I have to attach it?

Answer (score 0):

adding the canvas to the gridlayout instead of the widget solved this.

```
w = ChartWidget(self)
self.gl_main.addWidget(w.canvas, 4, 0, 1, 1)
```